# Illustrator 2022 to After effects 2022 - colors differ

Tags: after-effects

I am trying to import illustrator shapes into after effects. But when I import I get different colors for some reason.

This is original in Illustrator:
[image]

And this is what I get in after effects:
[image]

How can i fix this?

Answer (score 1):

You need to make sure you're working in the same [Colour Space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Color_space) in both products.

Colour Space in Illustrator:
https://helpx.adobe.com/illustrator/using/color.html

Colour Space in After Effects:
https://helpx.adobe.com/after-effects/using/color-management.html

sRGB is likely to work well in both, but if you're making animation for television, you'll probably need Rec709 colour space in After Effects.  This means you may need to convert your profile.